# Jquery / Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Trying to get the correct regex for this - only letters, spaces, hypens, and commas.  So far this only works if you only input 1 charactor.  Any more then that, and it returns false.  Anyone able to help?

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var locationtest = /[^a-zA-Z \-\.\,]/;
    if (!locationtest.test($('#location').val())) {
        alert('Nope, try again!');
        $('#location').val('')
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('You got it!');
    }

});`
```

Comment: Your expression is correct. See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, it matches 1 or more characters within the set you described

```
/^[a-zA-Z \-\,]+$/
```

I took out the `\.`, your description says letters, spaces, hyphens, commas

Comment: Oops, copied & pasted the \. from a PHP preg_match

Answer (score 0):

You're close, you just need to specify how many times you want the character to appear.

The following code would specify 0 or more times
    var locationtest = /[^a-zA-Z -.\,]*/;

And this code would specify 1 or more times
    var locationtest = /[^a-zA-Z -.\,]+/;

The importance being the * and + characters.

Answer (score 0):

Add a quantifier `+` and the global flag `/g`:

```
var locationtest = /[^a-zA-Z \-\.\,]+/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is correct, you just need to invert the match result.

```
/[^a-zA-Z \-\.\,]/
```

Will match if the string contains any char that is **not** what you want (the leading `^` in the character class).

I.e remove the `!`:

```
var locationtest = /[^a-zA-Z \-\.\,]/;
if (locationtest.test($('#location').val())) {
    alert('Nope, try again!');
    $('#location').val('')
    return false;
} else {
    alert('You got it!');
}
```

Note that empty string will pass as valid, if you don't want that, you can use this instead:

```
/[^a-zA-Z \-\.\,]|^$/
```